# Ember - filter our a model for the same model attribute for multiple values

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to filter the model based on multiple values for the same property?

Say I've got the following model with properties:

```
model a{
hasMany: b
}

model b{
belongsTo: a
belongsTo: c
}

model c{
hasMany: b
}
```

Now I want to do something like: from model a return all records where a.b.c.id = 1, a.b.c.id = 10.... Is there a way to filter out a model for multiple values, for the same model attribute? (maybe passing an array?)

Thanks

Comment: Are these pojos, Ember model instances, or Ember Data instances?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a filter! http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filter

assuming the "model" property in your controller is set to "model a"

```
var comparisonModel = this.store.find('model', 1);
var comparisonModel2 = this.store.find('model', 10);

var modelsIWant = model.get('b').filter(function(model){
    if(model.get('c') == comparisonModel || model.get('c') == comparisonModel2){
        return model;
    }
});
```

modelsIWant will be an array of only the models whose "c" relationship == those models

give this a try